# Iterating over user profiles in Sharepoint Online 2013

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, user-profile-service

With the on-premise instance of SharePoint, I am able to call the `GetUserProfileByIndex` from the User Profile Service to iterate over user profiles. However, with SharePoint online 2013, I get the following error when following the `NextValue` link: `This operation requires you to be managing your own data or have administrator privileges`. Now that could mean two things :

- My account is not properly configured for that. That seems unlikely since I use the credentials of a global admin and can access all user profiles with `GetUserProfileByName`.
- Since the SharePoint Online instance is shared, this approach is simply broken because I would need permission on the whole instance, including other tenants.

Is there a way of granting permissions to my account or an alternative to the User Profile Service for listing all user profiles ?

Comment: Which API are you using and which hosting method is being used?

Comment: @Stephen: I'm using the [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms583891.aspx](user profile SOAP service). My instance of SharePoint is hosted with Office 365, if this is what you mean.

Comment: Yip that gives me a better idea...

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Are you trying to get user profile properties for the current user?  You say below you don't know the username in advance, how/when are you getting it?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar but not using Webservices but using JS CSOM, not sure is this is an option for you but I found this useful.

[harePoint 2013: Working with User Profiles & JavaScript CSOM](http://vrdmn.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html)

Hope this helps

S

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know the usernames in advance and I am limited to the soap services for technical reasons. I guess I'll just retrieve the users on a per site basis with [GetUserCollectionFromSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.usergroup.getusercollectionfromsite.aspx), then retrieve their profiles by username.